# How to remove paginate in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, backend, illuminate

I need to remove the pagination and leave everything on one page, but this way I'm doing it only generates BUG.
I wonder why the snippet of the commented code doesn't work to remove the pagination.

```
if ($minParam || $maxParam) {
  $products = Product::whereHas('sizes', function ($query) use ($minParam, $maxParam) {
    if ($minParam && $maxParam) {
      $query->whereBetween('max_capacity', [$minParam, $maxParam]);
    } elseif ($minParam) {
      $query->where('max_capacity', '>=', $minParam);
    } else {
      $query->where('max_capacity', '<=', $maxParam);
    }
  })
    ->whereHas('solutions', function ($query) use ($solution_id) {
      $query->whereIn('solution_id', $solution_id);
    })
    ->where('active', 1)
    ->orderBy('position', 'ASC')
    ->get();
  //->paginate(16);
} else {
  $products = Product::whereHas('solutions', function ($query) use ($solution_id) {
    $query->whereIn('solution_id', $solution_id);
  })
    ->where('active', 1)
    ->orderBy('position', 'ASC')
    ->get();
  //->paginate(16);
}
return view('solutions.show')->with(compact('solutions', 'solution', 'products', 'ranges'));
```

}
}

The bug after replacing with get ()

ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::links does not exist. (View: /app/server/resources/views/solutions/show.blade.php)
Previous exceptions
Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::links does not exist.

Comment: What `bug` are you referring to? You're still making use of `->paginate()` so pagination is to be expected.

Comment: Exactly I need to do a pagination, but just taking it out and putting get () doesn't work.

Comment: You do need pagination, or don't need pagination? You've still not told us what the error message you're getting is. That would probably help.

Comment: What is the error you get? What is `)->
    
    if ($minParam || $maxParam)` supposed to do?

Comment: I want Remove pagination. I dont´t need pagination. 
posted error.

Comment: You posted the code from the vendor directory that throws an error. What is the **exact error message** that it's throwing? Also, show us the code where you've replaced `paginate` with `get`

Comment: `Collection::links` on `show.blade.php` <-- Your `show` view is still using the pagination links. Find that and take it out. The issue is not from the code you're showing here.

Comment: Understand. I found show.blade.php, now I'm going to look for where to change, the truth is that I don't know what to change hahahah

Answer (score 0):

try changing `->paginate(16)` to `->get()` in all of the code like this:

```
    whereHas('sizes', function($query)  use($minParam, $maxParam) {
         if($minParam && $maxParam) {
             $query->whereBetween('max_capacity', [$minParam, $maxParam]);
         } elseif($minParam) {
             $query->where('max_capacity', '>=', $minParam);
         } else {
             $query->where('max_capacity', '<=', $maxParam);
         }
     })->
    
    if ($minParam || $maxParam) {
      $products = Product::whereHas('sizes', function ($query) use ($minParam, $maxParam) {
        if ($minParam && $maxParam) {
          $query->whereBetween('max_capacity', [$minParam, $maxParam]);
        } elseif ($minParam) {
          $query->where('max_capacity', '>=', $minParam);
        } else {
          $query->where('max_capacity', '<=', $maxParam);
        }
      })
        ->whereHas('solutions', function ($query) use ($solution_id) {
          $query->whereIn('solution_id', $solution_id);
        })
        ->where('active', 1)
        ->orderBy('position', 'ASC')
        ->get();
    } else {
      $products = Product::whereHas('solutions', function ($query) use ($solution_id) {
        $query->whereIn('solution_id', $solution_id);
      })
        ->where('active', 1)
        ->orderBy('position', 'ASC')
        ->get();

 /*$products = Product::whereHas('solutions', function ($query) use ($solution_id) {
    $query->whereIn('solution_id', $solution_id);
  })
    ->where('active', 1)
    ->orderBy('position', 'ASC');*/
    
      return view('solutions.show')->with(compact('solutions', 'solution', 'products', 'ranges'));
    
    }
```

Comment: I changed -> paginate (16) to -> get () throughout the code, but the error persists. Do not place items on a single page.

Comment: @iLuucasD edit your question and show us the error you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

if you put paginate in default query. maybe using https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/pagination#paginator-instance-methods to get ->items from page, ->last_page, ->last_item you can combine in a function that loop and "join" pages items. i'll try it some day.